Is the ConfigureApplicationCookie(...) designed to allow us to configure an existing cookie by default in the default scheme (Cookies)?
I was implementing the remember me option in a login form in an asp.net core MVC project, so I ran into the topic of saving a token in a cookie and that a cookie must exist in a scheme. As I understand, there is a default scheme which is named as "Cookies" by default.
I'm currently confused about the ConfigureApplicationCookie(...) method, as I don't know to which scheme is that cookie that we are configuring related to.

Is it a cookie inside the Cookies scheme and if not, to which scheme is it related ?
Is it existing by default and we configure it or it is created when we invoke that method ?


You could check the source codes for the ConfigureApplicationCookie , this is the Identity library codes:
The source codes as below, it used to configure the Identity.Application scheme. Not your added cookie scheme.
Codes:
/// <summary>
/// Configures the application cookie.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services">The services available in the application.</param>
/// <param name="configure">An action to configure the <see cref="CookieAuthenticationOptions"/>.</param>
/// <returns>The services.</returns>
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureApplicationCookie(this IServiceCollection services, Action<CookieAuthenticationOptions> configure)
    => services.Configure(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, configure);

The result for the IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme is as below:

